# Selenium typing text at cursor active section

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to make tistroy auto upload program using python selenium.

I’ve referenced [https://3210w0.tistory.com/203](http://3210w0.tistory.com/203)

The problem is I changed the mode to use HTML tag.

In HTML mode, not using textarea or input tag. so I can’t use send_keys().

[image]

ex) browser.find_element_by_class_name(‘textarea_tit’).send_keys(title)

I think I should edit line 35~47

How can I code action like **click blue section and write some text**?

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem using switch_to.active_element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

using `ActionChains`

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editorContainer"]/div[1]/div[2]/textarea').click()
ActionChains(driver).key_down('test1').perform()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editorContainer"]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/pre').click()
ActionChains(driver).key_down('test2').perform()
```

Comment: Tistory HTML mode not using textarea. I tried it but it failed. I'll upload a picture for your reference. Thanks

Comment: I modified the script.

Comment: I solved the problem using switch_to.active_element. I'll try your answer. Thanks